# Swift: Working with Obj-C classes

Tags: swift

I'm playing around with Swift in Playground, I created a simple code that translates strings like `OneTwoThree` in `123`.
At beginning, I implemented it by checking uppercase / lowercase state of each char in a for loop, then I tried with Regular Expressions:

```
let regExPattern = "(?<=(^|[a-z]))[A-Z][a-z]+(?=([A-Z]|$))"
let regEx = NSRegularExpression(pattern: regExPattern, options: nil, error: nil)

let numbersRegEx = numberNames.map({(name: String) -> Int in

    let matches = regEx.matchesInString(name, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(name)))

    let digits = matches.map({(match:AnyObject) -> String in

        // lookupString return a String containing
        // the digit corresponding to the passed digit name
        // e.g.  lookupString("Three") -> "3"

        return lookupString(name[match.range.toRange()!.startIndex ..< 
                                 match.range.toRange()!.endIndex])

    })
    return String().join(digits).toInt()!

})
```

What I don't understand is why `matchesInString` gives me a `[AnyObject]` instead of `[NSTextCheckingResult]`, I bet it's because I'm receiving an Obj-C object, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an array of `AnyObject` back because while Swift has typed arrays (due to its generics support), Objective-C only has the untyped `NSArray`, which can contain any kind of object. The documentation states that `matchesInString()` returns an array of `NSTextCheckingResult` objects, but the compiler doesn't know this from the Objective-C method signature:

```
- (NSArray *)matchesInString:(NSString *)string
                     options:(NSMatchingOptions)options
                       range:(NSRange)range
```

However, you can cast this return value to an array of `NSTextCheckingResult` like this:

```
let matches = regEx.matchesInString(name, options: nil, 
        range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(name))) as [NSTextCheckingResult]
```

Unfortunately, this gives you a runtime error if nothing comes back, since `nil` can't be cast to an array, so you're better off either letting `matches` be an Optional:

```
let matches = regEx.matchesInString(name, options: nil, 
        range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(name))) as? [NSTextCheckingResult]
```

or using optional binding to safely access any results (this is nice since you can deal with the "not found case" easily in the `else`):

```
if let matches = regEx.matchesInString(name, options: nil, 
        range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(name))) as? [NSTextCheckingResult] {
    // process the matches
} else {
    // invalid number string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The official Apple documentation for matchesInString says:

```
- (NSArray *)matchesInString:(NSString *)string options:(NSMatchingOptions)options range:(NSRange)range
```

Given this signature, there is no way for Swift to know that your array will only contain objects of a certain type

Because it can't know, the Swift compiler has to translate it to the most generic possible result type, which is an Array of AnyObject (you do at least know only objects will be there, since the method originates in Objective-C).

Hence the [AnyObject] choice.
And, actually, absent any nullability information on the resulting NSArray, what you're getting is probably closer to an [AnyObject]! (the NSArray* could very well be nil, again absent nullability information) - the individual objects in the array can't be nil (NSArray doesn't support nil as an element), so assuming Swift knows that, there is no need for the AnyObjects to be themselves IUOs

Comment: Thanks, what is IUOs?